# Using 2 projects in one solution windows store application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am new to windows store application development at the moment having a problem using 2 projects in one solution is it possible to access 2 projects in one solution for eg:- i have written this action handler in the 1st project language select page

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        {

```
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "AllGroups");            
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage1), "AllGroups");
    }
```

}

GroupedItemsPage1 item page is in second project is it possible call GroupedItemsPage1 from the 1st project and if it is possible how to add namespaces to the 1st project

Comment: Will you please clear why you need 2 projects? Why both pages are not in same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's technically possible, but I have a feeling that what you're trying to accomplish doesn't require 2 projects. A common reason for having multiple projects in a single solution is to encapsulate resources that will be used in different places, say for instance in a class library that defined custom controls which you could then use in different apps.

It sounds to me like you might benefit from an introductory guide into windows 8 apps. Here is a video link I dug up quickly on google: [Windows 8 Store App Tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Build-your-first-Windows-Store-app/C-Part-1-Create-a-Hello-world-app)

If you are serious about learning windows 8 store app development then I recommend you go out and purchase a good book on the topic. If you are already an experience programmer, then I would recommend Charles Petzold's Programming Windows 6th edition. He does a stellar job introducing the principles behind windows 8 store app development, as well as covering advanced topics. Be warned that the book assumes you have at least intermediate programming experience.

Good luck and I hope this helps!